# Compressing a list

Tags: macros, programming

I have an application, where I am using lists to store reference numbers of forms as shown below:

```
\alist(1,2,3,4,4a,8,9,10,23,23b,28)
```

As these lists get rather long, I would like to compress them as follows:

```
\alist(1-4,4a,8-10,23...)
```

Can someone offer a solution? Perhaps an internal LaTeX macro?

Comment: There is code like that in `cite.sty` by D. Arseneau.

Comment: @egreg thanks for the suggestion. Also found something similar in sttools.sty, however the latter needs 70+ `expandafters`! Would you please write your comment as an answer so that I can accept it?

Comment: @Yiannis: is the list sorted?

Comment: @Bruno it is sorted.

Comment: I guess that any non-number should just stay where it is in the list? Or should `23a,23b,23c,` become `23a-c`? Is everything made from character tokens? letters and digits? (I'm probably going to provide a LaTeX3-based solution, but I'm curious to know how far it should extend.)

Comment: @Bruno I prefer 12-18,18a,18b,20-20 etc, which should make it easier, a LaTeX3 solution should be fine.

Comment: `20-20` if the range has only one element? What do non-numeric entries look like (to know how accurate that test should be): explicit character tokens, with only digits and letters? Should they be expanded?

Comment: @Bruno they are only explicit character tokens with only digits and letters. If it has only one element just the number and the separator i.e., 20,21.... I am also trying to develop one with traditional LaTeX. I have defined two separators one for the elements (,) and another for the range (-) in order to generalize the solution.

Comment: @Yiannis: I would personally use `--` as a range delimiter, since this allows negative numbers more easily.

Comment: @Bruno You right! I never thought of negative numbers.

Comment: @Yiannis. Oh well, I've gotten carried away in over-checking the input, and now I've got to leave `:(`. Good luck for the plain LaTeX macro.

Comment: @Bruno Thanks, so far ... nothing is working:)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is code that does something like you desire in [`cite.sty`](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/cite/) by D. Arseneau.